# Color the dots in itemize

Tags: tables, beamer

I want the dots in itemize item to be red colored. However, I don't seem to manage to get the dots to be colored red.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=red}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}\hspace*{\labelsep}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Deltafunctie}

\begin{definition}[Deltafunctie van Dirac]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
            \tabitem $\delta{(t)} = 0 \text{ als } t \neq 0$ \\
            \tabitem $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta{(t)} \,dt = 1$
          \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{definition}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: dots needs to be colored red]

Comment: The template is applied properly inside itemize environments, but for your `\tabitem`, any reason not to just use `\newcommand{\tabitem}{\textcolor{red}{\textbullet}\hspace*{\labelsep}}`?

Comment: @frabjous Yes, because I didn't know I could do that. Your suggestion has helped me!

Comment: As an aside, might I suggest using a `dcases` environment here? You're really not giving an itemization, but a system of mathematical constraints. As a bonus, you can choose the alignment yourself (e.g. the equals signs, with the t ≠ 0 condition automatically tabbed rightward), and have display-style math so that the integral is nicer.

Comment: If you want you can translate the header 'Definition' into Dutch by providing a new environment in the preamble (`\theoremstyle{definition}\newtheorem*{definitie}{Definitie}`) and then calling that in the frame (`\begin{definitie}\end{definitie}`).

Comment: @Mew Thank you for your suggestion. I have used `dcases` as an alternative now. I can see the value of this for the definition that delta =0 for t=/=0 however I don't see a nice implementation for the integral. Do you have a suggestion for that also?

Comment: @Marijn Thank you for your suggestion. I have added it to my presentation!

Comment: To apply the template color you need the starred-form, `\usebeamertemplate*{itemize item}`. Also inside `center` env why not use an `itemize` env directly.

Answer (score 1):

You are already setting the `itemize item` beamer colour, so you'll just have to apply it to your custom macro:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=red}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]
\newcommand{\tabitem}{{\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}\hspace*{\labelsep}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Deltafunctie}

\begin{definition}[Deltafunctie van Dirac]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
            \tabitem $\delta{(t)} = 0 \text{ als } t \neq 0$ \\
            \tabitem $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta{(t)} \,dt = 1$
          \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{definition}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```